# Why does there seem to be no "Opened" event for a WinRT XAML BottomAppBar?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, appbar

I want to respond to the opening of a bottom app bar in my Windows Store App. [Elsewhere](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/843107/Is-there-an-event-for-when-an-appbar-displays), I was advised that there is, indeed, and "Opened" event for it, but this:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Opened="bottomAppBar_Opened" >
```

...results in a red (unrecognized) "Opened", and the method name I entered does not generate a corresponding handler in the code-behind.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
private void bottomAppBar_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    appbarbtnOpenPhotosets.Enabled = PhotraxSQLiteUtils.DatabaseContainsRecords();
    appbarbtnCre8FilteredPhotoset.Enabled = appbarbtnOpenPhotosets.IsEnabled; // or call the 
        query again, if necessary
    appbarbtnClearMap.Enabled = MapHasMarkers();
}
```

...but what event can I use, or how can I hook into the opening of the appbar?

And actually, giving the Page's BottomAppBar a name was not allowed, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page.TopAppBar is an (attached) property, so you are trying to set a property on a property assignment. Moreover, as you see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.topappbar), the child of Page.TopAppBar must be an AppBar object.

So, you should do the following

```
  <Page.TopAppBar>
      <AppBar Opened="...">
          <!-- Here the AppBar's content -->
      </AppBar>
  </Page.TopAppBar>
```

Comment: In my case, it's a BottomAppBar, but I reckon the concept would be the same. But I don't have an "AppBar" child, but rather "CommandBar":
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar
Hopefully that will work as well - that is, hopefully CommandBar has an Opened() event (I'll czech it out when I get home).

Comment: CommandBar is a specialization of AppBar, as you see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx